# Unicode Character Display Problem

Tags: php, html

I am trying to show नेपाल at my page, but is shows à¤¨à¥‡à¤ªà¤¾à¤². What is causing the unicode to render like this.

Comment: Even if I am trying to print it only.

Comment: This is an encoding issue. You need to add more info about where the text comes from and what encoding you are using on the page

Comment: Are this characters hard-coded into the source code of your page? If yes, what text editor do you use to create HTML pages? It could be that the editor is saving the file using a different encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by something (likely the web browser) interpreting the characters as something else than Unicode. Browsers are quite bad at guessing the proper encoding, so it must be explicitly defined. Perhaps you should have something like this in the `head` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

It's also possible that the font being used does not cover those characters.

Answer (score 1):

Write at the top of the script `<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');?>`

Answer (score 1):

If the data comes from a database then this

```
$mysqli->query('set character set utf8');
```

should help. Put it inside your db connection :-)

Answer (score 0):

Reading from [unicode.org](http://unicode.org/help/display_problems.html):

> If you are unable to read some Unicode
>   characters in your browser, it may be
>   because your system is not properly
>   configured. Here are some basic
>   instructions for doing that. There are
>   two basic steps:
>
> - Install fonts that cover the
>     characters you need
> - Configure your
>     browser to use them.